# Download dynamic images concurrently

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I need to download images concurrently.All the image url's have been extracted from one of the request's response.I used regular expression extractor to capture all the image urls.And ProfileImagePath_matchNr varies.

```
ProfileImagePath_1="www.mydomain.com/img1.png"
ProfileImagePath_2="www.mydomain.com/img2.png"
ProfileImagePath_3="www.mydomain.com/img3.png"
ProfileImagePath_4="www.mydomain.com/img4.png"
ProfileImagePath_5="www.mydomain.com/img5.png"
ProfileImagePath_6="www.mydomain.com/img6.png"
ProfileImagePath_7="www.mydomain.com/img7.png"
```

Now I need to download all those images concurrently.I could not able to use jp@gc Parallel http request as the ProfileImagePath_matchNr is varying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to construct the list of URLs dynamically like:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('ProfileImagePath_matchNr') as int, { index ->
      sampler.addURL(vars.get('ProfileImagePath_' + index))
   })
   ```
3. That's it, the PreProcessor will retrieve all the images URLs from the JMeter Variables and add them as the targets for the [`jp@gc - Parallel HTTP Requests` sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler)

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn what do these `vars` and `sampler` variables mean